# Error during Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I'm getting this trace:

> (process: 462) GLib-WARNING **: getpwuid_r(): failed due to unknown user id (0)

I have Windows 7 currently installed on the machine, and was booting off a cd with the Ubuntu 10 ISO on it.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/531027

Answer (score 1):

That's a warning that has no impact on functionality whatsoever. It's purely cosmetic and can be safely ignored. After installing updates, it will no longer appear during those split-seconds of TTY-visibility in suspend, resume, TTY switching, boot, etc.